# How to change codepage in windows server 2016 by command?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, codepages

How to change codepage in windows server 2016 by command in powershell?

Comment: What is a codepage?

Comment: `chcp` still worked last I checked :-)

Comment: chcp, is a built-in utility, `chcp.com`, located in `C:\Windows\System32`. As it is not a built-in cmd.exe command, it should work in powershell.exe too.